# How do I fix this hoverable menu? It doesnt Work

Tags: html, css, menu, hover

I want to create a hoverable menu using HTML and CSS. Ive tried putting the dropdown content outside the navigation menu etc but None of These solutions worked. Ive reviewed the Code on several websites, showing the exact Same solution for only the hoverable menu. Therefore I guess the mistake is included in the Rest of the Code. Sorry for my Bad English, I Hope you Unserstand everything.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            body{
                background-color: #2B2E2B;
            }
            .menu {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                z-index: 9999;
                width: 100%;
                height: 6%;
                background: linear-gradient(to right, #aaf6e4 0%, #ff99cc 100%);
            }
            .blog{
                opacity: 0.7;
                margin-top: 10%;
                width: 9%;
                height: auto;
                margin-left: 4%;
                float: left;
            }
            .dropdown{
                float: right;
                margin-right: 7%;
                margin-top: 2%;
                position: relative;
                display: inline-block;
            }
            .menuname{
                opacity: 0.7;
                font-size: 100%;
                color: #2B2E2B;
                text-align: center;
                padding: 0%;
                background-color: transparent;
                border-style: none;
                float: right;
                margin-top: 2%;
                font-family: OCR A Std, monospace;
                outline: none;
            }
            .menusymbol{
                opacity: 0.6;
                margin-top: 0%;
                width: 9%;
                height: auto;
                float: right;
                margin-left: 0;
                transform: rotate(90deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
                -ms-transform: rotate(90deg;
                -moz-transform: rotate(90deg);
            }
            .dropdown-content{
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 1;
                display: none;
            }
            .line{
                
            }
            .line:hover{
                
            }
            .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content{
                display: block;
            }
            .dropdown:hover .menusymbol{
                transform: rotate(0deg);
                -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
                -ms-transform: rotate(0deg;
                -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="homepage" id="homepage">
            <nav class="menu" id="menu">
                <img class="blog" src="/img/blog.png">
                <img class="blog" src="/img/zeitleiste.png">
                <img class="blog" src"/img/user.png">
                <div class="dropdown">
                    <img  class="menusymbol" src="/img/three.png">
                    <button class="menuname" id="menuname">Test</button>
                    <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-content">
                        <a class="line">Blog</a><br>
                        <a class="line">Timeline</a><br>
                        <a class="line">About me</a><br>
                        <a class="line">Contact</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Btw the ">" at the end of "<!doctype html" is there in my Code, so that is not the mistake.

Comment: Then edit your question to add it

Comment: there are syntax errors, search for `rotate(0deg`, this needs a closing parenthesis. I found this in two places. Fix these and check again if the hover works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the mistake. It seems to work fine for me (when I add a background to the popup).

```css
body {
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}

.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  height: 6%;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #aaf6e4 0%, #ff99cc 100%);
}

.blog {
  opacity: 0.7;
  margin-top: 10%;
  width: 9%;
  height: auto;
  margin-left: 4%;
  float: left;
}

.dropdown {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 7%;
  margin-top: 2%;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.menuname {
  opacity: 0.7;
  font-size: 100%;
  color: #2B2E2B;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0%;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-style: none;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 2%;
  font-family: OCR A Std, monospace;
  outline: none;
}

.menusymbol {
  opacity: 0.6;
  margin-top: 0%;
  width: 9%;
  height: auto;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.dropdown-content {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  display: none;
  background: white;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
  display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .menusymbol {
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="homepage" id="homepage">
  <nav class="menu" id="menu">
    <img class="blog" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510__340.jpg">
    <img class="blog" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510__340.jpg">
    <img class="blog" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/19/08/32/marguerite-729510__340.jpg">
    <div class="dropdown">
      <img class="menusymbol" src="/img/three.png">
      <button class="menuname" id="menuname">Test</button>
      <div class="dropdown-content" id="dropdown-content">
        <a class="line">Blog</a><br>
        <a class="line">Timeline</a><br>
        <a class="line">About me</a><br>
        <a class="line">Contact</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Well this works, I also dont know where the difference ist But thank you

Comment: You're welcome. I think it was just the background lacking a background color, but glad to help.